# Partial fetch of association without fetching the whole list using Hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, associations, criteria

I have a one to many association that is defined the following way:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "root")
@Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
private Set<Content> contents;
```

The Content beans have a property called type:

```
@Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
private Integer type;
```

Now i would like to do a criteria query that fetches only contents of a specific type without fetching the whole list of contents:

```
session.createCriteria(Root.class, "root)
    .createAlias("contents", "contents", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("contents.type", 1))
    .list();
```

This fetches the correct associated beans (filtered by type eq 1) but as soon as i access the collection in the root beans using

```
root.getContents();
```

the full list is fetched again.

For performance reasons i want only the filtered associated beans to be fetched and the association set should not be updated to the full list on first access.

Up to Hibernate 3.6.3 this was the way Hibernate behaved. Seems as this was considered a bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2049

Is there any way to get the old behaviour in current Hibernate versions? Already asked in the bug ticket but never got any reply.